# Why ++[] throws an error but ++[[]][0] produces 1?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between these two following expressions? It seems to me, that incrementing `[]` is the same like incrementing `[[]][0]` since first element of this outer array is `[]` indeed.

```js
console.log(++[]);
```

```js
console.log(++[[]][0]);
```

Comment: It will be hard to find, but I'm pretty sure there's a duplicate somewhere.

Comment: I thought so as well, but I could not find it. Even SO duplicate finding algorithm couldn't.

Comment: `[] = [] + 1` clearly is invalid. `[[]][0] = [] + 1` is not.

Comment: `console.log(1+[]);` also works, so maybe it has to do with `[]` not being an L-value in `++[]`, i.e. the ++ requires an operand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`++` increments **and** assigns a value.

You can **assign** a value to a variable or to a property of an object.

`[]` is neither. You can't say `[] = [] + 1`.

`[[]][0]` is the first item (property with the name `0`) in the array (arrays are a type of object). You can say `someArray[0] = [] + 1` (even though with `++[[]][0]` the array is discarded as soon as the operation is complete).

Comment: this is clear: someArray[0] = [ ] + 1, confused most likely: [[ ]] [0]. Thanks Quentin :)

Comment: @Nit — You made a change which didn't express what I was trying to say. So I reverted it. Then I reconsidered.

Answer (score 0):

Using an array literal in my example is actually quite confusing. 
It gets much clearer when numbers are used.

[According to increment operator definition:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment)

> The increment operator increments (adds one to) its operand and returns a value.

```
++4
```

Now it is at least for me more obvious that one cannot add one to numeric literal.